# Mule datamapper nested array

Tags: mule, datamapper

Inside Mule datamapper, I am using XML to XML mapping. I want to map an input array source to a destination parent and child array. If I map the input to both parent and child, I can only see the output of the parent mapping. The child mapping is ignored. Any ideas how I can achieve that.

The mapping structure is like this:

```
Input side:
<inputElement> <!-- an array -->

Output side:
<parentElement> <!-- an array -->
   <childElement> <!-- an array -->
```

Now I need to map inputElement both to parentElement and childElement. 
I can see the inputElement -> parentElement output. But I can't see the output of inputElement -> childElement map.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Insert an example of the input and the expected output.

Comment: Answer the question with your solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by modifying the auto generated script for inputElement -> childElement map. I changed the line: `output.__parent_id = input.__parent_id;` to `output.__parent_id = input._id;`